# Presentations of groups

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

I'm trying to understand presentations of groups better than I currently do. Does anyone know of any good online sources that are worth a look?

Comment: Can you ask a more specific question? What is it that you don't understand?

Comment: Read: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group

Comment: It's more about finding a rigorous introductory source. A lot of pages seem to have major mathematical flaws or leave a lot unexplained etc

Comment: Then pick up a textbook, say, Lyndon and Schupp "Combinatorial group Theory". Also, why the tag "lie-groups"?

Comment: I've picked up a lot of textbooks that aren't thorough and have errors.
The tag lie groups is on here because Weyl groups (which are related to lie groups) are, as you know, very relevant to presentations.

Comment: OK, then try Lyndon-Schupp or Karrass-Magnus-Solitar "Combinatorial Group Theory".

Comment: @anonymousgoose: which are those errors? give an example, if you please

Comment: ^I appreciate the recommendation of textbooks. 
For example, I've read some texts that aren't entirely clear on the commutative maps between a set, the free group and the group itself. I feel like a lot of them are pretty vague as well - I'm unsure whether this is just because they assume a lot of prior knowledge or because the writer doesn't fully understand the subject themselves.

Comment: Could you give a specific example where exactly in the book their treatment is unclear; I think the references I listed are as clear as they can get.

Comment: It's hard to answer this as we don't know your current level of understanding. Please [edit] the question to include what you know already.

Answer (score 1):

For a brief overview of the theory of presentations of groups, you might want to have a look at [this short book by Derek Holt](https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/maths/people/staff/fbouyer/presentation_of_group.pdf).

If you have already finished it and want some more insight into the presentations of groups you might be interested in "Combinatorial group theory: presentations of groups in terms of generators and relations" by Wilhelm Magnus, Abraham Karras and Donald Solitar.